# jQuery Autocomplete combobox not working after update

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, autocomplete

I recently update jquery from 1.8 to 1.11 and the jquery combo-box blew up.

At first it was giving the error of _renderItem is undefined so after checking the few stackoverflow posts found that `input.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item )...` should be changed to `input.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item )`. This got rid of the the _renderItem issue but the entire combobox is not working at all. It just represents as a textbox with no functionality.

[image: combobox not working , and not displaying the dropdowns]
Here is the section of the code

```
input.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item )
        {                
            return $( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
        };
```

Please help me out, I have been stuck on this for last 6 hours...

Comment: Is it happening on every browser, or not just on IE7 or less?

Comment: All browsers, but I only need it on chrome.

Comment: I feel like a dumbass. This was already working but the problem was with the z-index of the drop down menus. The were appearing behind the container and it felt like they were not working. sometimes simplest things are hard to find, like missing semi colons and drop-down menus...

Answer (score 1):

Check out the upgrade guide from 1.8 to 1.9 in this link:

http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

You will notice that several things have changed, i.e.:

> Preparing for jQuery UI 1.10
>
> The API redesigns deprecate a lot of functionality, which will be removed in 1.10. You don't have to wait for the 1.10.0 release in order to find out if your code will work when the 1.8 APIs are removed. You can use the $.uiBackCompat flag to test this with any 1.9 release

Another example:

> Slider now uses ui-slider-handle-index instead of index.ui-slider-handle. Autocomplete now uses ui-autocomplete-item instead of item.autocomplete.

Try to find out what are the major changes from 1.8 to 1.9 and test. Then again, if that don't help, try again from 1.9 to 1.10 and so on.

Comment: Yup I was using the documentation. Thanks for referencing it though .